# Get pointer type of a reflect.Type

Tags: go, reflection

Assume I only have a [reflect.Type](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Type) `t`:

```
fmt.Println(t) //prints lib.Counter
```

I would like to get pointer type to this type, such that:

```
fmt.Println(ptrT) //prints *lib.Counter
```

How can I do this? `t` can be of any type, not only lib.Counter.

Also, what if I want to do vice versa? Like getting lib.Counter from *lib.Counter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [reflect.PointerTo](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/go1.18.4:src/reflect/type.go;l=1441).

To get the non-pointer type again, you can use [Type.Elem()](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.4:src/reflect/type.go;l=947).

```
thing := Thing{}
ptrThing := &Thing{}

thingType := reflect.TypeOf(thing)
fmt.Println(thingType) // main.Thing
thingTypeAsPtr := reflect.PointerTo(thingType)
fmt.Println(thingTypeAsPtr) // *main.Thing

ptrThingType := reflect.TypeOf(ptrThing)
fmt.Println(ptrThingType) // *main.Thing
ptrThingTypeAsNonPtr := ptrThingType.Elem()
fmt.Println(ptrThingTypeAsNonPtr) // main.Thing
```

Working example: https://go.dev/play/p/29eXtdgI9Xf

Comment: ok. what if I have `*lib.Counter` and I would like to have `lib.Counter`? what's the opposite of `reflect.PointerTo` ?

Comment: @johnydoey You can use `Type.Elem()`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in the following way:

```golang
ptr := reflect.PointerTo(reflect.Typeof(lib.Counter{})) // *lib.Counter
```

The variable `t` can be an arbitrary type:

```golang
ptr := reflect.PointerTo(t)
```

Comment: ok. what if I have `*lib.Counter` and I would like to have `lib.Counter`? what's the opposite of `reflect.PointerTo` ?

Comment: You can do `reflect.ValueOf(lib.Counter{}).Elem()`.

Comment: but assuming I do not have lib.Counter{}? Because the type can be anything else too, both primitives and non-primitives.

Comment: @johnydoey Are you asking how to create a `reflect.Type` for an arbitrary type?

Comment: @johnydoey I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. If you want to create a zero-value from type `t`, you can do: `reflect.Zero(t)`

Comment: As @RedBlue already said, the `reflect` API is quite independent of the type himself.